# Function call to set variable doesn't work

Tags: php

the following code is modified after suggestion does get the $i  $j works well

```
<?php
$i=1;
$j=1;

function fixIndex() {
    global $i, $j;
    $a=$j-$i;
    if ($a === 60){
        $i += 60;
    }
    $j++;
}
```

but it does not work on my main code as follow:

```
   $times = array();
   $values1 = array();  
   $values2 = array();
   $values3 = array();
   $values4 = array();

  $i=1;
  $j=1;

$file_lines = file($DispFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


foreach( $file_lines as $line_num => $line_value) {
fixIndex();
if ($line_num < $i)continue;  // skip records in 60* range
$line_elements = explode(",", $line_value);
$times[] = date("H:i:s", $line_elements[0]);
$values1[] = $line_elements[1];
$values2[] = $line_elements[2];
$values3[] = $line_elements[3];
$values4[] = $line_elements[4];
}
```

After the foreach loop I call for the fixIndex(), trying to get the $i value for the next line of code(if ($line_num < $i)continue;) to skip  60 records before i build an array. That $i doesn't seem to skip the record. If I change that $i to a number on it ($line_num < 60 )continue; Than it does skip the 60 records.
also is there any change of the program flow if this php program do a refresh on the every 10 sec on the web, What I mean is did $i and $j rest to 1 every time after refresh?
Thanks again to anyone for any help

Comment: `$i+5;` doesn't actually do much at all, unless you meant to update $i with that value - `$i = $i+5;`.... the code as you've written it does run, it just doesn't do anything with the calculated result of $i+5

Comment: @Felix Wong: I see you opened a new question as your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391535/parse-error-on-function-call/35391636?noredirect=1#comment58488640_35391636 has been closed as a duplicate. To my opinion a bit prematurely, and it is not really a duplicate, if one looks in detail at it. I tried again to understand what you really want your code to do and have added an answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pass by reference to avoid needing global variables here. What that means is the function will modify the variables that were passed to it.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

```
<?php
   function fixIndex(&$i, &$j) {
       global $i, $j;
       if ($j - $i == 5) {
           $i += 5;
       }
       $j++;
   }


   $i=1;
   $j=1;

   for ($k=0;$k<=20; $k++){
       fixIndex($i, $j);
       echo $i.'<br />';
       echo $j.'<br />';    
   }
?>
```

Also, I changed "$i + 5" (which doesn't make anything happen) to "$i += 5" so that it modifies the variable $i.

Comment: Thanks for this code .it works on it own. but it does not work on my main code my main code as follow:

Comment: Bit of a cliffhanger there, is there more code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing your incremented value of `$i`.

```
<?php
   $i=1;
   $j=1;
   function fixIndex() {
   global $i, $j;
   if ($j - $i == 5){
   $i = $i+5;
   }
   $j++;
   }
   for ($k=0;$k<=20; $k++){
   fixIndex();
   echo $i.'<br />';
   echo $j.'<br />';    
   }
```

Demo : https://eval.in/518511

Answer (score 0):

You probably could describe what you want to do like this:
"***increment $i by 5 every time $j has grown by 5***".
This could be implemented in a straight and very compact form like this.
(The solution covers all cases, and is not depending on the upper limit of the iteration.)

```
<?php
    function fixIndex(&$i,$j) {
        if ( ($j>1) && (($j-1) % 5 == 0) ) $i += 5;
    }
    $i = 1;
    for ($j=1;$j<=20; $j++){
        fixIndex($i,$j);
        echo "\$j=$j, \$i=$i  <br />";
    }
```

Notes:

> ( ($j-1) % 5 == 0 )

…means: when $j -1 can be devided by 5 without a remainder (% 5 = "modulo 5").

> function fixIndex(&$i,$j)

**&**$i means that a reference (pointer) to the memory of the $i variable is accepted instead of its value. This is necessary since the function is modifying the value of $i. So, you would not need the *global* statement.
On the other hand the $j variable is not modified and thus can be accepted as a value.

Result:

> $j=1, $i=1 
>   $j=2, $i=1 
>   $j=3, $i=1 
>   $j=4, $i=1 
>   $j=5, $i=1
>
> $j=6, $i=6 
>   $j=7, $i=6 
>   $j=8, $i=6 
>   $j=9, $i=6 
>   $j=10, $i=6
>
> $j=11, $i=11 
>   $j=12, $i=11 
>   $j=13, $i=11 
>   $j=14, $i=11 
>   $j=15, $i=11
>
> $j=16, $i=16 
>   $j=17, $i=16 
>   $j=18, $i=16 
>   $j=19, $i=16 
>   $j=20, $i=16